# S3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have different objects that produce file that are saved in S3. Each object call the following function to save the file.

I have the following issue only with few objects. The objects either always save files or can never save the files.

```
    /**
     * Upload a file (with metadata).
     *
     * @param bucketId    the id of the bucket
     * @param key         the key of the file
     * @param inputStream the content of the file
     * @param metadata    the metadata of the file
     * @return the eTag of the uploaded file
     * @throws IOException If an error occurs during the file upload
     */
    public String upload(String bucketId, String key, InputStream inputStream, Map<String, String> metadata) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Upload file {} on bucket {} with metadata: {}", key, bucketId, metadata);
        CreateMultipartUploadRequest.Builder builder = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder();
        if (!this.encryptionAlgorithm.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
            builder = builder.serverSideEncryption(this.encryptionAlgorithm);
        }
        CreateMultipartUploadRequest createMultipartUploadRequest = builder.bucket(bucketId)
            .key(key)
            .metadata(metadata)
            .build();

        CreateMultipartUploadResponse createMultipartUploadResponse = s3Client.createMultipartUpload(createMultipartUploadRequest);
        String uploadId = createMultipartUploadResponse.uploadId();

        try {
            List<CompletedPart> parts = uploadFileParts(bucketId, key, uploadId, inputStream);

            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeMultipartUploadRequest = CompleteMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketId)
                .key(key)
                .uploadId(uploadId)
                .multipartUpload(CompletedMultipartUpload.builder().parts(parts).build())
                .build();
            CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeMultipartUploadResponse = s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(completeMultipartUploadRequest);

            return completeMultipartUploadResponse.eTag();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while uploading {} multipart {} on bucket {} with metadata {}", key, uploadId, bucketId, metadata, e);

            s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(AbortMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketId)
                .key(key)
                .uploadId(uploadId)
                .build());

            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The error is

**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 79b6c0a2-0d74-1f30-a4bf-246e9631ccd8, Extended Request ID: null)**

I verify, the bucket is always the same value, the input stream data contains the data of the file. The data are transmitted successfully to the S3 bucket. The key is always like `eventsnapshot-21234-7-2021-08-12-1628767690000.jpg`.

Did you already had such of issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. If metadata value have a white space at the end, the signature generated by the AWS SDK will not be the same as the one returned by the server.

Probably that S3 trim the name and values of metadata.

Later I found also a similar issue in the aws-sdk-go:  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2448

I'm using the version 2.15.36 of aws-sdk-java. I don't know if it was fixed in newer version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue is caused when the filename contains special characters(like ©). I have set the filename as metadata for the S3Object.
In order to fix the issue, I have removed those special characters from the filename.

**Reference Links:**

- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7630
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2577
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html

> User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata keys in lowercase.
> Amazon S3 allows arbitrary Unicode characters in your metadata values.
> To avoid issues around the presentation of these metadata values, you should conform to using US-ASCII characters when using REST and UTF-8 when using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST.
> When using non US-ASCII characters in your metadata values, the provided unicode string is examined for non US-ASCII characters. Values of such headers are character decoded as per RFC 2047 before storing and encoded as per RFC 2047 to make them mail-safe before returning. If the string contains only US-ASCII characters, it is presented as is.

**My Environment:**

- springboot: 2.6.6
- aws-java-sdk-s3: 1.12.131
- httpclient: 4.5.13